# Induced maps of the circle exponents

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, winding-number

Consider the family of circle self maps $\{f_n:S^1\to S^1:x\to x^n\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$. How can we compute the induced maps $f_{n*}$ on the $1$-st simplical homology $H_1(S^1)$?

**Thought** $H_1(S^1)=\mathbb Z$ has for homomorphisms multiplication by an integer and no other homomorphisms. So $f_{n*}$ acts by multiplication with an integer. How can we see that it is multiplication with $n$?

Would it be useful to consider paths and their lifts to the universal cover? Could we consider the path $f(t)=e^{2\pi i t}$ and the composition $f_n \circ f$? I could not go far with this thought.

**EDIT:** I wanted to compute the induced maps on singular homology not simplical homology. Mr. Frenek resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, it just says that the image of $f_n$ goes $n$ times around the circle which is clear.

Let $T$ be a triangulation of the circle that consists of $3|n|$ edges, and let $S$ be a triangulation of the circle that consists of $3$ edges, assuming the usual orientation. Note that $f_n$ is homotopic to a *simplicial* map $g_n: T\to S$ that sends each of the $3|n|$ 1-simplices of $T$ to a $1$-simplex of $S$ in a consecutive way, "just around the circle" (both maps have degree $n$). The generator of $H_1(T)$ is the sum of all $3|n|$ simplices and this is sent to $n$ times the generator of $H_1(S)$ (which is the sum of all $3$ simplices).

**Edit** Based on the discussion, it seems to me that there is some confusion in your question: in simplicial homology, you need to have simplicial complexes and maps. True, the results are independent on the triangulation and any continuous maps between simplicial complexes can by approximated up to homotopy by a simplicial map between suitable *subdivisions*.

I'm not completely sure what are your definitions and sources, but my feeling is that the following idea might help you to unknot it. Let $T$ be a regular $3|n|$-gon and $S$ a triangle as above, and consider $h_1$ to be a homeomorphisms $T\to S^1$ that sends the *first* edge of $T$ to $S^1$ via $t\in [0,1]\mapsto e^{2\pi i t/(3|n|)}$ where the first edge of $T$ is linearly identified with $[0,1]$. Similarly, it maps the "second edge" of $T$ "linearly" to the circle via $t\mapsto e^{2\pi i (t+1)/(3|n|)}$ and so on. Similarly, choose a homeomorphism $h_2$ that maps $S$ to $S^1$ so that it maps the first edge $\simeq [0,1]$ via $s\mapsto e^{2\pi i s/3}$ and so on. Then the following diagram commutes (commutes *exactly*, not only up-to-homotopy, which would be also good enough).
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
T & \stackrel{g_n}{\to} & S\\
\downarrow^{h_1} & &\downarrow^{h_2}\\
S^1 & \stackrel{f_n}{\to} & S^1
\end{array}
$$
The vertical arrows are orientation-preserving homeomorphism and take the generator of $H_1$ (in whatever sense) to generators of $H_1$ and the upper horizontal map is my simplicial map that "just multiplies by $n$" on the homology level, as shown above.

If your definitions of induced maps in simplicial homology are reasonable enough---whatever they are---you should be able to formalize this within your framework.

Comment: Thank you, sir. What do you mean when you say that $f_n$ is homotopic to a simplical map $T \to S$? Two functions can be homotopic only if they have the same domain and the range of one is a subset of the range of the other, can they not?

Comment: You can either consider $T,S$ to be triangulations *of the circle $S^1$* -- that is, $T=S=S^1$ as topological spaces. Or altenatively, you may realize $T$ and $S$ as "regular polygons in the plane" and then clearly, both $T$ and $S$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$ via orientation-preserving homeomorphisms and apply the reasoning to my $f_n: T\to S$. But I should rather ask you: what does it mean an "induced map in simplicial homology" which is in your question? In simplicial homology, you can only deal with simplicial maps. Depending on *your* interpretation, you choose the right setting.

Comment: Any continuous map $f$ induces a homomorphism on homology groups. First, we define the map $f_#$ sending simplexes to simplexes via composition. $f_# (s) = f\circ s$. We extend $f_#$ to sums of simplexes by linearity. Moreover, $f_#$ commutes with the boundary operator, i.e. it defines a chain map. Therefore, $f$ induces a homomorphism of homology groups.

Comment: You see now why I don't understand your claim that $f_n$ is homotopic to a simplical map. To me a simplex is a map from the canonical simplex to the topological space in question. A triangulation with $3n$ edges is a collection of $3n$ 1-simplices, i.e. they are $3n$ maps $s:[0,1]\to S^1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not the issue. We can consider a triangulation to be the union of the images of the simplixes. Really, how can we see that $f_n$ is homotopic to your simplical map?

Comment: @Student It seems to me that the deeper problem is this: can you explain *in which sense your map $f_n$ is simplicial (and if it is not, what do you mean by $(f_n)_*$)*? Maybe once you clerify this, everything else will be clear too.

Comment: I'm not claiming that $f_n$ is simplical. I encountered this notion in your answer for the first time. I should assume that by simplical you mean a map sending a simplex to another simplex. Moreover, I explained already how $f_n$ induces a chain map. This map factors down to the level of homology.

Comment: You claim that $f_n$ is homotopic to the simplical map $g_n$ between $S^1$ and $S^1$ that sends the images of the simplexes in $T$ to these in $S$ just around the circle. Intuitively this must be so, but then again intuitively already knew that the winding number of $f_n$ is $n$. I'm sorry, I cannot prove that $f_n$ and $g_n$ are homotopic.

Comment: *"Moreover, I explained already how $f_n$ induces a chain map."* I'm not completely sure about this. You wrote that $f_\#$ sends simplices to simplices via $f_\#(s)=f\circ s$ but it doesn't make much sense to me: in which sense is $f\circ s$ a simplex? In *singular* homology, continuous maps naturally induce homomorphisms on homology, but in *simplicial* homology, you need to have a triangulation and simplicial maps. It seems to me that the confusion is on a deeper level and I recommend to carefully check your definition and sources.

Comment: I apologize. After going back to the texts I realized that I am describing the induced map on singular homology and this is indeed what I want to compute. I want to compute the winding number of the map that winds around the circle $n$ times. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You can consider the triangulations $T,S$ of the circle to be singular chains (formal sums of singular $1$-simplices $\simeq [0,1]$ via $h_1, h_2$). The induced map maps the sum of the $T$-simplices to $n$-times the sum of $S$-simplices. It remains to prove that the sum of the $T$- resp. $S$-singular simplices is the generator of the singular $H_1(S^1)$, which reduces to the natural isomorphism between singular and simplicial homologies. To compute a winding number, you don't need homology. Just look how many times you cross $1\in S^1$ in the positive direction minus in the negative direction.